# How can i use litecoinj(carete wallet return public address &send money to another address)?

Tags: litecoin

[image: Use createWalletAPI buy litecoinj]

why in this line(peerGroup.downloadBlockChain();) I can't connection peer?? I'm confuse.

Comment: Do you have a local litecoind instance?

Comment: No,But I Download litecoinj in github,how can i get the litecoin instance client ? I gratitude that, buy the way, I run bitcoinj use the main.class in java, and i can see the bitcoin wallet , how can litecoind use it ? i'm confuse.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the code that you're running expects to be able to connect to localhost and download the blockchain. Since there is no litecoin instance listening locally, this will not work.

Install [litecoin](https://litecoin.org/), and run it.

Comment: I Download the litecoin client and run it,this is litecoin wallet client , I want to use run litecoin java code , should I use litecoin wallet client and change this wallet network to test ?